# Wait For a Specific Window BatchScript

Tags: batch-file

How can I pause BatchScript till a windows with a specific title is launched?
I want to use a command for waiting for a window title instead of using Sleep command to delay the script for some seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TASKLIST` command maybe. For example:

```
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"
```

will find and filter all tasks whose executable name is `cmd.exe`. Like wise you can do it by Window Title, using

```
TASKLIST /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq something"
```

Answer (score 2):

AppActivate return value says whether it switched to a particular window or not. When AppActivate is sucessfull the Window exists.

Comment: BTW. If you stated your problem rather than your solution we could give specific advice.

Answer (score -1):

For delay proposes, you can use ping, something like this:

```
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 1
```

Comment: The question is explicitly about waiting until a window with a specific title is launched, how does sleeping helps here?